# Android: How to copy a SQLite database from one application to another

Tags: android, file, sqlite, copy, io

I have a lite version of an application that uses a SQLite database. I want to copy that database over to the full version of the application when the user installs the full version.

I have written some code to perform the file copy, but the lite database file always comes up as unreadable. The file is there and I can point to it, but I can't read it to perform the copy.

In the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), we read:

> You can save files directly on the
>   device's internal storage. By default,
>   files saved to the internal storage
>   are private to your application and
>   other applications cannot access them
>   (nor can the user).

Note the words, "by default".

Is there a way that I can override that default and make the SQLite file readable by my other application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 options.

1. Set the sql database to be [world readable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE) on creation.  You can do this by setting the appropriate mode parameter in the call to openFileOutput() or openOrCreateDatabase().
2. Set the [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId) attribute in the manifest of both of your applications so that they have the same user ID.  This treats both applications as the same user, giving both applications access to the same private set of files.

Comment: Note that if you have already published the lite application, *do not change the* `sharedUserId`. Others have tried it and locked themselves out of their own updates. Only use `sharedUserId` on unpublished projects, not ones that are already in distribution.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. I don't think I'll be able to use the "WORLD_READABLE" approach because I'm creating the database using SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(...). Regarding the "sharedUserid" approach, however, that may be an option. I currently have the full version of the application in the Market. I am planning on releasing the lite version. Neither yet has a sharedUserId. If I add the sharedUserId to both now, do you foresee me having any problems? Thank you.

Comment: As CommonsWare mentioned, if you already have an app published, changing the sharedUserID will be problematic.  To be useful, you have to set the sharedUserID on both apps.  You may want to take a different approach, perhaps add functionality for the lite version to copy the database to the sdcard or public location and then copy it down with the full version.

Comment: Thank you, Error 454. I have considered doing exactly what you suggested, but my concern is that not all users will have an SD card. I am currently working on setting up a custom Content Provider so the full version can pull the data out of the lite version's database and stuff it into its own database. That seems to me to be a good solution - if i can get it working.  :^)